# How to apply percentile ranking on the pivot table?

Tags: python, statistics

How to apply percentile ranking on the pivot table ?

Dummy Dataset

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Business": ["Hotel","Hotel", "Transport", "Agri", "Tele","Hotel", "Transport", "Agri", "Tele"],
"Location": ["101","101", "101", "101", "103",'105','102','103','106'],
"Area" : ['A','A','A','A','B','C','D','B','F']})
```

[image]

```
activity_cat_countby_subarea = df.groupby(['Area', 'Location','Business']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
activity_cat_countby_subarea = activity_cat_countby_subarea.reset_index().sort_values(['counts'], ascending=False)
```

[image]

After converting to the pivot table here I am applying the ranking on the overall count level.

```
activity_cat_countby_subarea['overll_pct_rank'] = activity_cat_countby_subarea['counts'].rank(pct=True)
```

[image]

But my requirement I need to apply the ranking based on each business count. i.e I need to find the ranking for each business i.e "hotel" and their count.

Kindly assist let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

```
activity_cat_countby_subarea['overll_pct_rank'] = activity_cat_countby_subarea['counts'].rank(pct=True)
```

Do this:

```
activity_cat_countby_subarea['overll_pct_rank']=activity_cat_countby_subarea.groupby(['Business','counts']).rank(pct=True)
activity_cat_countby_subarea.sort_index(inplace=True)

#Output

    index   Area    Location    Business    counts  overll_pct_rank
0   0       A       101         Agri            1   0.5
1   1       A       101         Hotel           2   1.0
2   2       A       101         Transport       1   0.5
3   3       B       103         Agri            1   1.0
4   4       B       103         Tele            1   0.5
5   5       C       105         Hotel           1   1.0
6   6       D       102         Transport       1   1.0
7   7       F       106         Tele            1   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Apologies I just updated the question. Kindly check

Comment: I followed your suggestion, percentile output is same for all the locations.

Comment: Updaed my answer...kindly have a look

Comment: Hi, When I applied the above group method in the real dataset the percentile ranking is showing wrong. But if applied per column value results are correct. I am not sure why group percentile and per column percentile are different.

Comment: group percentile are calculating the rank of `'Bussiness' and 'counts'` combined whereas per column value calculating the rank according to that column itself

Comment: Exactly will modify the code according to the column value.